# Output written to screen then to output file?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, console, output

Basically I had to read in some data from an input file and do some calculations to calculate the total-staff cost per unit, the input shown below in the following format

```
<shop unit>
<sales assistants>
<hours> <rate>

Unit One 
4 
32 8 
38 6 
38 6 
16 7 

Unit Two 
0 

Unit Three 
2 
36 7 
36 7
```

Goes upto 9 shop units..

I then had to allow a user input which is the "Recommended maximum"(RM) and compare it with the total staff costs per unit. If the total staff cost per unit is less than or equal to RM then the details must be written to the screen and to an output text file called results.txt. If the amount is larger than RM then the results must be written to the screen only. 
Anyways here is my code below, and the bit im having problems with is the output mentioned above, Only shop unit 9 is printing to the output file and most of the time nothing prints to the console:

```
if (total > reccomended_max) {
    System.out.println("The total staff wages for " + Unitnum + " is £" + total + ", therefore it is larger than the RM");
} else if (total == reccomended_max) {
    System.out.println("The total staff wages for " + Unitnum + " is £" + total + ", therefore it is equal to the RM");
} else {
    System.out.println("The total staff wages for " + Unitnum + " is £" + total + ", there it is less than the RM");
}
```

I have shortened my code, because it has a lot of else if statements, What design pattern is suitable for removing many if and else or else if statements?

Comment: Can you format your code to make it more readable?

Comment: How you mean to make it more readable?

Comment: Edit your question and use proper tabbing/spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't delegate `System.out`! Instead, simply write the result to both streams if required:

```
if (total > reccomended_max){
    String message = "The total staff wages for " + ...;
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true))) {
        out.println(message);
    } // here, the stream will be automatically flushed and closed!

    System.out.println(message);
} else {
    System.out.println("The total staff wages for " + Unitnum + " is £" +total + ", therefore it is lower than the RM");
}
```

Comment: Uhmm doesn't appear to be working, Have I got the positioning of my IF statement in the correct location ?

Comment: @user2863681 sorry, I forgot to set the 'append' flag for the FileOutputStream. Without, the file will always be overwritten. Now it should append every time the stream is created.

Comment: Note that it is even better to open the stream only once at the beginning. So you can move the try(...) statement before your loop and the closing bracktes afterwards.

Comment: Ah ok, Only seem to be getting shop 'unit one' output into the file, it's not doing the calculations for unit 2-9 too ?

Comment: @user2863681 see my minor change: creating FileOutputStream with a second parameter (true) now. This enables appending (default: false = overwriting existing file).

Comment: Strange. I tried your code with my changes and input file from above. Works. (For shop-units 1-3)

Comment: Uhmm, Could you paste the full code into the answer? :) Sorry i'm abit confused on the positioning of everything, only been doing java afew weeks